Hardwood over black mastic
I am redoing the hardwood floors in about 700 sq ft of my house. This area sits above an unfinished basement on joists. In demoing the kitchen, we found that a small piece of tile had asbestos. I think that small piece was the only piece of tile in the space.
The floor I’m removing is floating LVP that is on 1/8” plywood stapled to the original subfloor. I carefully removed one panel and found black mastic on the original subfloor. It is about 150 sq ft of the 700.  I have it out for an asbestos test, and assuming it is positive, what should I do?
One plan is to just pay for professional remediation. Another is remove the 1/8 plywood and paint over it with an encapsulating primer. Or I could just lay 1/8 plywood in the other space to make it all level. We are installing solid hardwood.
I appreciate the input here. My risk tolerance is pretty low.

Asbestos is bad if you start sanding it without a mask.  If you leave it alone, it leaves you alone.  Professional equals big money, paint or cover it, costs a lot less and does the same job as far as safety.  Asbestos wants long term(years) working with it to be dangerous(miners, installers, sprayers).

Thanks. Definitely not sanding. Wondering if I can remove the 1/8 safely and just encapsulate. I suppose if I wet it as I remove it.
